# SDL with OpenGL (freeglut) crashes on call to glutBitmapCharacter

Tags: c++, sdl, freeglut

I have a program using OpenGL through freeglut under SDL. The SDL/OpenGL initialization is as follows:

```
// Initialize SDL
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

// Create the SDL window
SDL_SetVideoMode(SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H, SCREEN_DEPTH, SDL_OPENGL);

// Initialize OpenGL
glClearColor(BG_COLOR_R, BG_COLOR_G, BG_COLOR_B, 1.f);
glViewport(0, 0, SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0.0f, SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

I've been using glBegin() ... glEnd() blocks without any trouble to draw primitives. However, in this program when I call any glutBitmapX function, the program simply exits without an error status. The code I'm using to draw text is:

```
glColor3f(1.f, 1.f, 1.f);
glRasterPos2f(x, y);
glutStrokeString(GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13, (const unsigned char*)"test string");
```

In previous similar programs I've used glutBitmapCharacter and glutStrokeString to draw text and it's seemed to work. The only difference being that I'm using freeglut with SDL now instead of just GLUT as I did in previous programs. Is there some fundamental problem with my setup that I'm not seeing, or is there a better way of drawing text?

Comment: If you are on linux, try to run it from valgrind, it will give you point where is an memory error.

Answer (score 2):

[Section 2, Initialization](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node9.html):

> Routines beginning with the glutInit- prefix are used to initialize
>   GLUT state. The primary initialization routine is glutInit that should
>   only be called exactly once in a GLUT program. **No non- glutInit-
>   prefixed GLUT or OpenGL routines should be called before glutInit.**
>
> The other glutInit- routines may be called before glutInit. The reason
>   is these routines can be used to set default window initialization
>   state that might be modified by the command processing done in
>   glutInit. For example, glutInitWindowSize(400, 400)  can be called
>   before glutInit to indicate 400 by 400 is the program's default window
>   size. Setting the initial window size or position before glutInit
>   allows the GLUT program user to specify the initial size or position
>   using command line arguments.

Don't try to mix-n-match GLUT and SDL.  It will end in tears and/or non-functioning event loops.  Pick *one* framework and stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have likely corrupted the heap.